# Is there a way to change a bootstrap react card component's border size?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-bootstrap

Reading through bootstrap react's [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/#api), I found that the API includes border color... and that was pretty much it for border. Does anyone know if you can customize the size (width) of the border as well? I also tried to write some custom css to overwrite the border, adding the `Bootstrap-Card` className attribute to the `<Card>` component, but what I tried did not work:

```
//index.scss

.Bootstrap-Card {
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: red;
}

//index.js

<Card className="Bootstrap-Card" style={{ width: '50rem' }}> ...
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Import css like this:

   import styles from "./App.module.css";

Use your class with following syntax:

```
<Card style={{ width: "18rem" }} className={styles.cardCustomized}>
```

2. You can also import like this:

   import "./App2.css";

and then use a string directly in className:

```
<Card style={{ width: "18rem" }} className="card-customized">
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-danny-56cow6

Comment: Do you need to import the styles like that and use jsx because it is a Bootstrap component and not like a regular div? I have no problem using something like className="App" for other components.

Comment: I updated my answer and codesandbox. No, it's not React component specific. I just don't see how you import your index.scss in index.js. But both ways are possible.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, and nothing was styling. However, I think I figured out that it was because I was importing bootstrap styling with `@import "./bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";` below the custom styling, so bootstrap overwrote it. When I moved the import to above the custom css, it applied as it should. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should import bootstrap only once and not in every scss file

Comment: I did only have it imported once, I was saying that I had imported bootstrap css below the custom styling, so the custom styling was overwritten by boostraps css in my index.scss file.